# Prevent Button Background from being scaled

Tags: android

I have a button with a background property, but when I add a padding to the button, the background scales too. Is there any way from preventing this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't add padding. The entire purpose of adding padding is to make the background larger.

Comment: But I can't make it absolute either because I'm working with images for hdpi en ldpi